# Rename files to md5 sum + extension (BASH)

Tags: linux, bash, rename, batch-rename

I need some help with a bash script. Script needs to rename all files in a directory to its md5 sum + extension.

I have found the bash script below, but it needs to be changed so that it will add the extension.

```
md5sum * | sed 's/^\(\w*\)\s*\(.*\)/\2 \1/' | while read LINE; do mv $LINE; done
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
# mkdir temp && cd temp && touch file.{a..e}
# ls
file.a  file.b  file.c  file.d  file.e
# md5sum * | sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\(\..*\)\)$/mv -v \2 \1\3/' | sh
`file.a' -> `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.a'
`file.b' -> `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.b'
`file.c' -> `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.c'
`file.d' -> `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.d'
`file.e' -> `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.e'
```

Or GNU sed can do it even shorter:

```
# md5sum * | sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\(\..*\)\)$/mv -v \2 \1\3/e'
```

Comment: The Apple/OSX version is: `md5 * | sed -e 's/MD5 (\([^.]*\)\(.[^)]*\)) = \(.*\)$/mv -v "\1\2" \3\2/' | sh`

Comment: If you have a large number of files on OSX: `ls -1 | while read file; do md5 "$file" | sed -e 's/MD5 (\(.*\)\(\.[^\d]*\)) = \(.*\)$/mv -v "\1\2" "\3\2"/' | sh ; done`  ( This extends from @fnl's version to handle a case where I had a timestamp with a decimal in some file names )

Comment: This solution may not be able to handle filenames with spaces, beware. I have a few files that doesn't work with this and they all have spaces

Answer (score 16):

I would go this route:

```
for F in $DIR/*.*; do
  mv "$F" "$(md5sum "$F" | cut -d' ' -f1).${F##*.}";
done
```

Use `${F#*.}` to get everything after the first period, e.g. `tar.gz` instead of `gz` (depends on your requirements)

Comment: OSX: `for F in $DIR/*.*; do mv "$F" "$(md5 "$F" | cut -d' ' -f4).${F##*.}"; done`

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -exec mv \{\} "`md5sum \{\} | sed 's/ .*//'`.`echo \{\} | awk -v FS='.' '{print $NF}'\"
```

Or something like this will do :-). Actually, I'd recommend to add a filter to the filenames for the find command as it will fail on files without a `.` in their name.

HTH