# How to rename files inside folder to its corresponding md5sum?

Tags: php, bash, md5sum

I have large samples in a folder with `plain names and file names with spaces also` and i want to renames all the files to its corresponding md5sum.

I tried this logic `for f in $(find /home/SomeFolder/ -type f) ;do mv "$f" "$(md5sum $f)";done`

But this is not working properly with some error like `mv: cannot move to` indicating no such directory.

Also i tried this logic [Rename files to md5 sum + extension (BASH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201729/rename-files-to-md5-sum-extension-bash) and tried this `for f in $(find /home/Testing/ -type f) ;do echo`md5sum $f`;mv $f /home/Testing/"echo`md5sum $f``"; done;
`
But it is not working.

Any suggestions to solve this.

I want to replace a file to its md5sum name without any extension

`sample.zip --> c75b5e2ca63adb462f4bb941e0c9f509`

`c75b5e2ca63adb462f4bb941e0c9f509c75b5e2ca63adb462f --> c75b5e2ca63adb462f4bb941e0c9f509`

`file name with spaces.php  --> a75b5e2ca63adb462f4bb941e0c9f509`

Comment: Did you achieved this with a bash script? why you dont execute that script from php, with the folder as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> See Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls` or `find` in a for-loop, [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs),

If you have `file names with spaces also` recommend using `-print0` option of `GNU findutils` for the job which embeds a `\0` character after file name with `read` with a null delimiter as below.

Run the script below inside `/home/SomeFolder` and use find from the current directory as

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    mv -v "$file" "$(md5sum $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
done< <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

The depth options ensure the current folder `.` is not included in the search result. This will now get all the files in your current directory ( remember it does not recurse through sub-directories) and renames your file with the `md5sum` of the filenames.

The `-v` flag in `mv` is for verbose output ( which you can remove) for seeing how the files are to be renamed as.

Comment: Error log `mv: cannot move '/home/Testing/results.json' to '7d3a4c935678a2233222b370655a6c11  /home/Testing/results.json': No such file or directory
`

Comment: @BackdoorCipher: Can you run it inside the `/home/folder`

Comment: `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do  echo  "$file" "$(md5sum $file)"; done< <(find /home/Testing/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
/home/Testing/file.txt d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /home/Testing/file.txt
`

Comment: See md5sum gives md5sum along with name.I think there is problem there.

Comment: @BackdoorCipher : it should work! Can you kindly confirm again?

Comment: `843617.html  
nsadmin@research:/media/all_hashes$ md5sum 843429.pdf
6506c1c794fc4fc5d5217155d40e0e3d  843429.pdf
nsadmin@research:/media/all_hashes$ locate 6506c1c794fc4fc5d5217155d40e0e3d
 ls | grep "6506c1c794fc4fc5d5217155d40e0e3d"

`

Comment: @BackdoorCipher: It is not possible to understand code in comments, update it as part of the question.

Comment: @BackdoorCipher: With the `-v` flag in `mv` flag, you should have seen which file is renamed to what, did you see the pdf file you mentioned when you ran the script?

Comment: Finally : Found my mistake,there is one file with file name as some 100 spaces then _564.doc . I manually removed it

Comment: @BackdoorCipher: Glad that you found it and fixed it, update in question, that part you claimed that was not working,.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a php script, something like below would work. This would go through all the files, rename them and then if successful delete the old file.

```
$path = '';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        if (substr($file, 0, 1) == '.') {
            continue;
        }

            if (rename($path . $file, $path . md5($file)))
            {
                unlink($path . $file);
            }

    }
    closedir($handle); 
}
```