# Rename files to hash and extension

Tags: linux, bash, rename, batch-rename

The question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201729/rename-files-to-md5-sum-extension-bash) to the OP's liking, but I couldn't make it work 100% for me. What I want to do is take files in `/home/hermit/Documents/Pictures` and hash it before putting the new files in `/home/hermit/Documents/HashPictures`, while keeping the file in `/home/hermit/Documents/`. Unfortunately, the solution **doesn't** seem to work for GIFs and JPGs.

> Or GNU sed can do it even shorter:
>
> `# md5sum * | sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\(\..*\)\)$/mv -v \2 \1\3/e'`

Another thing that would be nice is if I could have a script that is easily read or an explanation to go along with the script.

EDIT: These are the remaining files (in `/home/hermit/Documents/Pictures` and terminal output. Remaining files: [File names inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4NAZ.png)

```
hermit@hermit:~/Documents/PicturesHashed$ ./hash.sh
mv: target '9c48b6846aa3211ba867d9775aa9a730.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '6cef7445eb7382aa719e364dc2d0126c.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target 'b3624eae0010f7d042af838859d5ea0e.png' is not a directory
mv: target '12f8f700cc73abe05da61103184f2ed0.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '340e018ba57016f469a1039fb19c2619.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '89da545ea3084500cd86a6265676173c.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '7ff0671fc0447ca009d216670a0e2ac9.gif' is not a directory
mv: target '300d7e1e9807701f1a5043de85992484.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target 'c340521eec897957c0a7d6f415232ae4.png' is not a directory
mv: target '263ef6fd0b8623227a705bbcecb61755.gif' is not a directory
mv: target '2f4e522461ff467d5b4a09b7d33c2114.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '2372edeb385381540d2230266ad5a4d2.png' is not a directory
mv: target 'bf5fc13be51d281347e0b00694c7689b.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '3ab04030a8d06ff5aa5dca406c3927b0.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '84d61abe2ff50e81d96e9b5ca916048e.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target 'c1c74496d880e4a20403c65e583dff54.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '99c2a10e1f4ce27a08eafb70cbac09c1.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '7ff0671fc0447ca009d216670a0e2ac9.gif' is not a directory
mv: target 'e27c3fe527a6417e13f2b55865b77d4f.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target 'd32b6aa0ff3929b477fe5e33872220d1.png' is not a directory
mv: target '70df8a56449a7b19b286e0b77394a7c8.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '7e9b7446ea3fe662fa7ba3ba45952cbf.jpg' is not a directory
mv: target '975de97e64c345cbe41532101636c70e.gif' is not a directory
mv: target 'c3a691daa3400f00c87de37703ddd222.jpg' is not a directory
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
mv: target 'ce14ef4371c5fe6a61a539a9f22e6227.jpg' is not a directory
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Can you show an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: This code doesn't care about file types I suspect your problem is something different. Perhapse spaces in the file names.

Comment: New information. Also, it appears you're right, Philip Couling. How can I get the script to accommodate for special characters?

Comment: Regular expressions are frequently described as write only code. I think this is a good example.

Comment: Is there any other method? I have yet to take a programming class and as I said this isn't my code. :P

Comment: Yes, I'm working on an answer but it will take me a little while to format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this easier to read and follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir=/home/hermit/Documents/Pictures
destination_dir=/home/hermit/Documents/HashPictures

for file in "${source_dir}"/*;do

    hash=$(md5sum "${file}"|cut -d' ' -f1)

    ext=${file##*.}

    cp -v "$file" "${destination_dir}/${hash}.${ext}"

done
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! While an explanation would be nice, I feel like I understand this enough to be fine even without knowing the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

**Part A - What you've seen**

> Or GNU sed can do it even shorter:
>
> `# md5sum * | sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\) \(.*\(\..*\)\)$/mv -v \2 \1\3/e'`

I personally hate using `sed` for these cases if I was given this to review in professional code would reject it because it is so darn hard for future readers to understand.

Sed is a stream editor.  You feed stuff into it edits it and then pushes out the result.  It uses [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match patters on its input and then do something with them. Regular expressions are very hard to read even when you've worked with them for a while so I don't expect a lot of people to be able to read the above code.  People tend to use it because it can do a lot with very little code.

Sed has a lot of party tricks, and in this case its being used to execute other commands (`mv`).

`md5sum *` is producing an output like this:

```
263620ac1a08b934b5312f416fe7a1af  IMAG0001.jpg
972eddbf8e368a9c3d38e66bcf924cbc  IMAG0002.jpg
94b30dfedb8afb7143268d1c329d7e64  IMAG0004.jpg
c592b83172e7f3c2d20207ee4e0cdd0d  IMAG0005.jpg
1bc861c1251d87aea5e98ff263e09e79  IMAG0223.jpg
560afa8d60ff833a9dee52eff2fc420b  IMAG0224.jpg
```

Sed is then editing that to look like this:

```
mv -v  IMAG0001.jpg 263620ac1a08b934b5312f416fe7a1af.jpg
mv -v  IMAG0002.jpg 972eddbf8e368a9c3d38e66bcf924cbc.jpg
mv -v  IMAG0004.jpg 94b30dfedb8afb7143268d1c329d7e64.jpg
mv -v  IMAG0005.jpg c592b83172e7f3c2d20207ee4e0cdd0d.jpg
mv -v  IMAG0223.jpg 1bc861c1251d87aea5e98ff263e09e79.jpg
mv -v  IMAG0224.jpg 560afa8d60ff833a9dee52eff2fc420b.jpg
```

Sed is then executing this code.

Now you understand that, you can most likely pick out the `mv -v` and swap it for a `cp` or other command.  But you are still going to have problems with spaces and special characters.

---

**Part B - A more robust solution**

I would avoid `sed` altogether.  If you don't understand it then don't use it.  MOST people don't understand it.

```
for file in *.jpg
do
    sum=`md5sum "$file"`
    #remove the file name from md5sum's output
    # this is using bash's pattern matching but can be swapped out
    sum="${sum% $file}"
    cp "$file" "HashPictures/$sum"
done
```

Notice that I have put quotes round both `$file` and `$sum`.  Also we deal with one file per command, never one command for every file.  This way spaces in file names are never mixed up with spaces used to split command arguments.

---

**Part C - Final Thoughts**

For this example code I've used `cp` to put a copy of the image in a new directory.  That might not be what you want.  For example use `ln -s "$file" "HashPictures/$sum"` to create a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). This will avoid the need to duplicate the files and save a lot of space.

Comment: That's a bash/shell script, right? Also, I can see that the script probably doesn't work for all extensions at once. Good explanation, though.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, Philip Couling! Good explanation.

Comment: Sure.  bash / sh and if you change `*.jpg` to `*` it will catch all extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Rename all files not dirs in the current dir to

```
md5sum * | awk '{print "mv", $2, $1 ".jpg"  }' | bash
```

or

```
 md5sum -- * | awk '{print "mv --", $2, $1 ".jpg"  }' | bash
```

if files start with minuses.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Digest::MD5 qw{ md5_hex };

my ($source, $target) = @ARGV;

$source =~ s/(\s)/\\$1/g;

for my $file (glob "$source/*") {

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";
    my $content = do { local $/; <$fh> };
    my $digest = md5_hex($content);

    my ($extension) = $file =~ /\.([^.]*)/;
    open my $out, '>', "$target/$digest.$extension" or die "$file: $!";
    print {$out} $content;
    close $out;
}
```

Run as

```
perl script-name -- "source-dir" "target-dir"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python solution. Put this in a Python file in the same directory you want to convert (or modify the `'.'`).

```py
import hashlib
import os

def file_as_bytes(file):
    with file:
        return file.read()

def hash_file(fpath):
    return hashlib.md5(file_as_bytes(open(fpath, 'rb'))).hexdigest()

for fname in os.listdir('.'):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
    hash = hash_file(fname)
    dst = hash + ext
    print(fname + " --> " + dst)
    os.rename(fname, dst)
```