# How to rename files with output from program in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, mv, md5sum

I've been trying to find a simple, one-line solution to rename all files in a directory with their md5 hash. I've thought about using `find -exec` but I don't know how to pipe the results of `md5sum` to mv. I've tried permutations of

```
find . -exec md5sum {} | mv {} \;
```

and

```
find . -exec mv {} `md5sum {}`
```

Perhaps there's a better  way of going about it? Please advice a total beginner. All help is appreciated.

Comment: do you need to done this job with find command ?
you  can simply write where simple script to to this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the answer from: [Rename files to md5 sum + extension (BASH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201729/rename-files-to-md5-sum-extension-bash)

By modifying a little bit it will do exactly what you want (I already edited the command for you):

```
md5sum * | sed -e 's/\([^ ]*\)  \(.*\)$/mv -v "\2" \1/' | sh
```

Example of output:

```
'a' -> 'b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1'
'b' -> '26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510'
'c' -> '6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03'
```

Comment: I see. Thank you- this command works for files in a single folder. I am not familiar with sed- I would very much appreciate being pointed out to resources which would help me modify this so it could work for subfolders, if they're available.

Comment: `echo  > 'a b || RM -fr * ; '`

Comment: In other words, QUOTE the filenames before passing them to `sh`

Comment: @tunawolf Ok, so I would advise to create a script (Bash, Python, or whatever). It will be simplier that using a big one line command, specially if you are not too much familiar with some command line.